# What is the probability of the office being deemed functional?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

An IT office consists of 10 computers of which exactly 4 are working. To check if the office is functional, officials inspect four of the computers picked at random (without replacement). The office is deemed functional if at least three of the four computers are working. What is the probability of the office being deemed functional?

**My Solution:**

$E$ be event of office being deemed functional.

$E = 3$ out of $4$ computers working or all four computers working

$P(E) = P(3~\text{out of}~4~\text{computers working}) + P(\text{all four computers working})$

(3 out of 4 computers working)={WWWD,WWDW,WDWW,DWWW} where W,D are Working, Defective computers respectively.

(all four computers working)={WWWW}

$P(3~\text{out of}~4~\text{computers working}) = \frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 6}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7} \cdot 4 = 0.114$

$P(\text{all four computers working}) = \frac{4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1}{10 \cdot 9 \cdot 8 \cdot 7} = 0.004$

$P(E) = 0.114+0.004 = 0.118$

**Solution Provided is:**

$P(3~\text{out of}~\text{4}~\text{computers working}) = \frac{{4 \choose 3}{6 \choose 1}}{{10 \choose 4}}$

$P(\text{all four computers working}) = \frac{{4 \choose 4}{6 \choose 0}}{{10 \choose 4}}$

The sum of these approximately equals my solution. Looking at the formula though I feel it should not work. The denominator ${10 \choose 4}$ is not size of the sample space for given problem, since all $10$ elements are not distinct. Also ${4 \choose 3}{6 \choose 1} = 24$ is not the number of possibilities that satisfy the condition ($3$ out of $4$ computers working), only $4$ possibilities satisfy this. Why does this answer still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two answers are numerically exactly the same.  Yours is $\frac{576}{5040}+\frac{24}{5040}=\frac{600}{5040}$ and the provided solution is $\frac{24}{210}+\frac{1}{210}=\frac{25}{210}$.  Both are $\frac{5}{42} \approx 0.1190476$.

The factor of $4!=24$ in the numerator and denominator is simply the number of ways of ordering the four selected computers. You distinguished the orderings while the provided solution did not.

Comment: I did not understand "The factor of 4! in the numerator and denominator" part of you answer. Could you please explain it a bit more?

Comment: Also is ${4 \choose 3}{6 \choose 1}$ = 24 number of possibilities that support event $(3~\text{out of}~\text{4}~\text{computers working})$ ?

Comment: ${4 \choose 3}{6 \choose 1}$ is the number of ways of choosing which three of four working computers are selected and which one of six non-working computers are selected.   With those four selected computers, you can order them in $4!$ ways, which means ${4 \choose 3}{6 \choose 1} 4!$ will be the same as your earlier $4\cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 6 \cdot 4$

Comment: I see where I went wrong. All this while I did not consider 10 computers as distinct. I grouped them into two (faulty and working) with duplicate elements. ie; $WWWF$ has $\frac{4!}{3!}$ whereas it should have been $W_1 W_2 W_3 F_1$ which has 4! ways of arranging. Thank you for the help.